# How can I implement dependency to the gem "acts_as_votable"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm using `acts_as_votable` This gem is really useful. But one thing that I want.

That's dependency.

When user is deleted, related votes records also should be deleted.

However, this gem didn't create the model called "models/vote.rb"

So I cannot write this

**user.rb**

> has_many :votes, :dependent => :destroy

If possible I also want to add deleted_at attribute to this model so that I can use logical deletion.

How can I solve this while I'm using this gem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way:
Fork the gem.
Apply your patch.
Point your Gemfile to your own repository.
Bonus: Offer a pull-request of your code to the owner.

Stupid way:
Look into acts_as_votable and check what the method applies to your model.
Swap the two in your model and correct the association to include dependent: :destroy